# Searching long PDFs with adobe reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I am trying to search a very lengthy PDF (8000 pages +) for names. The last time I had the PDF open I could search a name and it would find it instantly. Now everytime I search a name it looks through every page and takes forever. I am using Adobe Reader X, is my index cache not working, or how can I fix it so it is fast again?